# Salesforce REST API with PHP, INVALID_SESSION_ID after successful authentication

Tags: php, curl, salesforce

I connected my web app to salesforce and successfully followed all the steps in the web server OAuth flow to get an access_token and related info:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeorder.meta/api_placeorder/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm

Every step seems to return the expected set of results specified in the docs, but when I try to make requests with the final access token, I get an error saying my session ID is invalid. Here is my code:

```
    // Execute a request for access_token and related info
    $output = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($output);

    // Extract token and instance_url from output
    $sf_url = $output->instance_url . '/services/data/v35.0/';
    $sf_auth = 'Bearer ' . $output->access_token;

    // Execute a new cURL request with auth values
    $ci = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_URL, $sf_url);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Accept' => '*/*',
        'Authorization' => $sf_auth,
        'X-PrettyPrint' => 1
    ));

    $output2 = curl_exec($ci);
    curl_close($ci);
    var_dump($output2);
```

The dump from $output gives:

```
object(stdClass)#194 (7) { 
["access_token"]=> string(112) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
["signature"]=> string(44) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
["scope"]=> string(3) "api" 
["instance_url"]=> string(27) "https://cs10.salesforce.com" 
["id"]=> string(68) "https://test.salesforce.com/id/xxxxx/xxxxx"
["token_type"]=> string(6) "Bearer" 
["issued_at"]=> string(13) "1453358xxxxxx" }
```

The dump from $output2 gives:

```
string(75) "[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]"
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

I also tried using the username-password auth flow, and I'm getting the same result. I can get an access token, but I can't query the database, and the error being returned is the same INVALID_SESSION_ID.

I used the Postman plugin for chrome, passed in all the same info for the username-password flow, and it works for making queries. I'm not sure what is being done differently, seems like all the data being passed is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had the wrong syntax for setting the curl headers. I tried to pass the values as an associative array, but the correct way is like this:

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization:' . $sf_auth,
    'X-PrettyPrint:1'
));
```